# Creating an If -> then statement for a formula field (long list)

Tags: formula, custom-field, formula-field

We have a list of 30 countries with specific rates at which our company must withhold taxes, and we wish to create a formula field in Salesforce to automatically compute the rate based on the user's country. This is straightforward to setup, but the current syntax we have isn't suitable for a long list like this.

For example: 
If UserCountry=UK, 0%
If UserCountry=Australia, 5%
If UserCountry=Bangladesh, 0%
etc....

What would be the best syntax to use for this?

Comment: I believe you're looking for the `Case` function: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions_a_h.htm&language=en_US#CASE

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this with the [case](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions_a_h.htm&language=en_US#CASE) function.

```
// As noted in the comments
CASE(expression,
value1, result1,
value2, result2,
else_result)
```

Above, if the value in expression is `==` to `value1`, the field value will be `result1` and so on. If no `values` match the expression, the field value will be `else_result`.

For your use case:

e.g.

```
CASE(UserCountry, 
"UK", 0%,
"AU", 5%,
etc...)
```

Comment: Small note, the final value in a `CASE` will be an `else`. EX: `CASE(expression, value1, result1, value2, result2,...,else_result)`

Comment: @JesseMilburn Edited the answer to include your note, Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the help!It looks like I am running into a syntax error: CASE(TEXT(Request__r.UserCountry__c),
“United States", 0%,
“United Kingdom", 0%,
30%)

Answer (score 0):

@Daniel Foster the values need to be in double quotes too.

`CASE(TEXT(Request__r.UserCountry__c), “United States", "0%", “United Kingdom", "0%", "30%")`